# How to pick up one variable (among several) in FLASK, using AJAX

Tags: javascript, python, jquery, ajax, flask

I am trying to pick up a variable in Flask from Ajax. The idea is to select a value from a dropdown list in HTML, then pass its ID to Flask using Ajax. The ID of the option is actually the variable name I want to import from Flask.

**Eg.:**
1-> I select the first option in the dropdown, which has the ID **'column_a'**;
2-> In Ajax, the ID pulled from the selected option, I pass to Flask using the variable **'labels_x'**;
3-> In Flask, I use the same variable name **'labels_x'** to receive the data from Ajax;
4-> And here comes the issue: I was supposed to pick up the global variable in Flask (**'column_a'**), according to the data received through 'request.args.get()', which is also **'column_a'**. But I just can't. All I get is a string 'column_a'. Not the values of the list stored in the global variable I want.
What am I doing wrong here?

## My dropdown list:

```
<select name="select_label_1" id="select_label_1" class="custom-select select_label">
    <option value="{{ column_a }}" id='{{ column_a }}'>{{ label_a }}</option>
    <option value="{{ column_b }}" id='{{ column_b }}'>{{ label_b }}</option>
    <option value="{{ column_c }}" id='{{ column_c }}'>{{ label_c }}</option>
</select>
```

## Ajax:

```
labels_x_selected = $("#select_label_1").children(":selected").attr("id") || 0;



// AJAX FOR LABELS
// ################
$.ajax({
  url: "/home/data_analysis_labels",
  type: "GET",
  data: {labels_x: labels_x_selected},
  success: function(data) {
    $("#labels___").html(data);
  },
  error: function(xhr) {
    alert('error - must try again and handle it');
  }
});
```

## Flask:

```
@blueprint.route('/data_analysis_labels', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def data_analysis_labels():

    global column_a
    global column_b
    global column_c

    labels_x = request.args.get('labels_x', default='nothing received', type=str)

    return jsonify(labels_x)
```

Answer (score 0):

## Answering my own question:

One of the possibilities is to create several If conditions like below. It just doesn't sound very readable and easy to do, since I have a hundred variables by now.

```
if labels_x == 'column_a':
    labels_x = column_a
else: labels_x = 'nothing received 2'
```

Then I get the global variable values instead of a simple string.